# Xamarin Forms navigation stack memory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, xamarin.forms

Is Xamarin Forms navigation stack garbage collected? When I click to button and open a page using Navigation.PushAsync() it will keep other page in navigation stack or relase memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigation stack is a Stack interface, which you can generally think of like a stack of silverware in a drawer.  When you add a fork to the drawer, you put it on top of the other forks, and when you remove a fork you always remove the top one.  A stack is a first-in-last-out data type.  When you do add a fork on the top, though, all the other forks are still there below it.

This is the same with the navigation stack.  When you add a page using `PushAsync(newPage)`, `newPage` is placed on the top of the navigation stack, but all the pages before it are still below it.  That way when you call `PopAsync()` you will return to the previous page and it won't have to completely remake it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: after clicking on Back  and after going to newPage  it gives me error NulReferenceException